# Calculating and verifying Time To First Byte (TTFB)

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, pagespeed, firefox-developer-tools

I was given the following formulas to measure Time To First Byte (TTFB), TTFB to DOM Ready and Page Load.

**TTFB**

```
window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

**TTFB to DOM Ready**

```
window.performance.timing.domComplete - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

**Page Load**

```
window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
```

Are these formulas correct? And how would I be able to check them? I've heard you can measure them in Firebug's *Network* panel, but it seems overall cumbersome in retrieving the values. Not sure where you get the values in Chrome.

So, how to determine those measurements?

Comment: Where did you get those formulas from?

Answer (score 9):

Firebug actually makes it very easy to see those timings. You just need to execute `window.performance.timing` in its command line and it will display a graph and lists all timings below like this:

[image: <code>window.performance.timing</code> display in Firebug]

Also, according to the [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming), I'd say your calculation should start at `fetchStart`, as that is the moment in time when the browser is ready to fetch the document using an HTTP request. Depending on your definition of *DOM Ready* the end time of that measurement may also be the `domInteractive` or `domContentLoadedEventStart` time.

So, I'd say the correct measurements would be:

**TTFB**

```
window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.fetchStart
```

**TTFB to DOM Ready**

```
window.performance.timing.domInteractive - window.performance.timing.fetchStart
```

**Page Load**

```
window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.fetchStart
```

Comment: That Firebug timing chart doesn't look accurate - I doubt the browser waited until the whole html was received, to start DOM parsing it.

Comment: You're right, the graph is incorrect regarding the *DOM Processing*. It currently (Firebug 2.0.14) refers to the time from `responseEnd` to `loadEventStart`, while it should actually be the time between `domLoading` and `domInteractive` or `domComplete`. I've filed [issue 7993](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7993) for that. Non-the-less you can read the correct timings from the table.

Answer (score 3):

This can be confirmed using Chrome's network tab:

**Example TTFB:**

`window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.requestStart`

[image]