# Measure network latency (time to first byte) from the client with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make client JavaScript choose the server that has the lowest network latency.  Currently, the client makes `XMLHttpRequest`s to all the servers, and chooses the one that loads the fastest.

However, I've noticed that the time from calling `send()` on the request to the time the response is received comprises of a significant amount of time where the request has not yet been sent at all.

Here's a screenshot of Chrome's developer tools:

[image: Screenshot]

As can be seen, the "Waiting (TTFB)" time (in green, with the red arrow pointing at it) is the network latency that I want.  However, there is a significant amount of time spent in the "Stalled" and the "Initial connection" states.  The amount of time spent in those states (especially "Initial connection") vary significantly between requests so my existing way of computing the minimum latency can give incorrect results.

Google talks about the meanings of each section [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing).

The [`XMLHttpRequest.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) property doesn't seem to be able to do what I want either.  I guess I would need a state somewhere between `OPENED` and `HEADERS_RECEIVED` to represent that the request has been sent, and then measure the time until the state is `HEADERS_RECEIVED`. (Or am I missing something here?)

So, is there any way to measure the time that I want, or at least measure something close?

Comment: It looks like I need the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API).  It measures XMLHttpRequests too, instead of just the original request.

Comment: Yup, I was just about to comment that. FWIW the Performance Timing API looks to have the same data as the Resource Timing API, so you can use [those formulas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35324845/5743988).

Comment: @4castle  Yeah, that link led me to google for "performance timing in xhr".  For my case though, since I only want the green region and not the orange region (see my image in the question), I think `responseStart - requestStart` is what I want.

Comment: Has there been an update to the formula? Because the keys I see in ResourceTiming don't have responseStart and requestStart. There's only requestTime.